# What should I write in qsub for checkpointing automatically?

Tags: linux, matlab, shell, hpc, qsub

`checkpoint.mat` 
is my checkpoint file.
`job.m` is my matlab file.

When my job exceeds 24 hours, it is terminated by the server. I implemented checkpointing in my own matlab file.
But what should I write in my qsub file?
Here is what a link, https://wikis.nyu.edu/display/NYUHPC/Tutorial+-+Submitting+a+job+using+qsub, wrote:

```
[-c checkpoint_options]
              n  No checkpointing is to be performed.
              s  Checkpointing is to be performed only when the server executing the job is shutdown.
              c  Checkpointing is to be performed at the default minimum time for the server executing
                 the job.
              c=minutes
                 Checkpointing is to be performed at an interval of minutes, which is the integer number
                 of minutes of CPU time used by the job. This value must be greater than zero.
[-C directive_prefix] [-d path] [-D path] [-e path] [-f] [-h]
```

But from here, I still cannot figure out how to write checkpointing once the job exceed the maximum allowed time, which is 24 hrs in my case. I want the job to be resubmitted once every 24 hours, from the state of checkpointing each time. I am also not from NYU, so is there a different syntax in qsub file to specify checkpointing?

This is what I wrote in my pbs:

```
.....
#PBS -c c=1440 minutes
....
```

But it does not work.

Comment: Two questions: 1) What's your Torque version? 2) Are you using BLCR for checkpointing?

Comment: @clusterdude 1) from`qstat --version` I get Version: 6.0.2 2)yes.